# Is $f(z)=\bar z$ complex differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, differential

Show that the function $f(z)=\bar{z}, z \in \mathbb{C},$ is not complex differentiable at $0$, but is differentiable in the real sense at all points in $\mathbb{C}$.

I am trying to brush up on some old complex analysis notes and I can't seem to figure this proof out. I am guessing that "in the real sense" is referring to real differential numbers. From here on I am stumped, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I might be wrong, but I don't think that's differentiable anywhere on the complex plane.

The equation doesn't satisfy the CR equations.

Comment: Yeah i was just looking at that. I noticed that too, that f(z) isn't holomorphic at any point in C.

Comment: I just am not sure why this is asked at 0 and how it is differentiable in the real sense in C.

Answer (score 2):

It is not complex differentiable, or holomorphic because the limit

$$\lim\limits_{z \to z_0} \frac{\bar{z} - \bar{z_0}}{z-z_0}$$

Does not exist for any $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. However we can interpret it as the map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ sending $(x,y)$ to $(x,-y)$ which certainly has a total derivative in the real multivariable sense. In particular, since this map is linear it is it's own total derivative at any point.

Answer (score 0):

In the real sence this will be:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\frac{(x,-y)-(x_0,-y_0)}{\Vert (x-x_0,y-y_0)\Vert}$$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\frac{(x-x_0,-y+y_0)}{\Vert (x-x_0,y-y_0)\Vert}$$
$$=\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\frac{(x-x_0,0)}{\Vert (x-x_0,y-y_0)\Vert}-\lim_{(x,y)\to(x_0,y_0)}\frac{(0,y-y_0)}{\Vert (x-x_0,y-y_0)\Vert}=0$$

Answer (score 0):

If it were complex differentiable, then it would satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. So if we put $z=x+iy$, then

$$f(z)=x-iy.$$

Where $u(x,y)=x,v(x,y)=-y.$ By C-R equations, we have

$$u_x=v_y, u_y=-v_x.$$

So $u_x=1, v_y=-1$ and by C-R we'd arrive at
$$-1=1$$

which is absurd!! Hence, $f(z)=\bar{z}$ is not complex differentiable.